# Rundeck update to 3.2

Tags: grails, devops, rundeck

I have updated Rundeck on my centos server from 3.1 to 3.2.6 using yum update rundeckd. After the update, **the existing projects are not showing up** unless i create a new test project. The value in framework.properties is set to /var/lib/rundeck/projects as per the documentation. What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because Rundeck now stores the projects in the default H2 database by default instead of filesystem, you can check the configuration in the `rundeck-config.properties` file:

```sh
# Encryption for project config storage
rundeck.projectsStorageType=db

rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.type=jasypt-encryption
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.path=projects
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.config.password=02f0dc8d21f4e26e
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.config.encryptorType=custom
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.config.algorithm=PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC
rundeck.config.storage.converter.1.config.provider=BC
```

More info [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/configuration.html#storage-types).

Good advice is to move your configuration to "real" RDBS as backend, take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/).

EDIT: You can store (and see your previous projects) on the filesystem changing `rundeck.projectsStorageType=db` by `rundeck.projectsStorageType=filesystem` .

Comment: I understood that rundeck uses the H2 Database as default. But even before the update, my rundeck service was configured to use H2 database. So what changed here ? And also moving the configuration to a RDBS is not an option for me right now.

Comment: Yeah, in previous versions Rundeck stored job definition data in H2 database and Projects in the filesystem, now save the projects on H2 too. But you can change projectsStorageType=db by rundeck.projectsStorageType=filesystem and you can see your projects on the filesystem. Remember that the H2 database is only for testing, the best and secure way to store your data is to use a real database as backend.